# Critical Caching issue in Laravel Application (AWS Server)

Tags: laravel-5, caching, amazon-ec2, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am facing a critical issue in my application, it is developed in Laravel and Angular. The issue is I am getting the old email templates on live site and on local server I am getting the latest updated one. The process to deloy the code is automatic, I just to commit the code in BitBucket and after that Bitbucket Pipleline push the code to AWS server directly.

I have already run the cache cammands for Laravel and restarted the jobs but still i am getting the same issue. If anyone have expirienced the same issue or have knowledge of the same to resolve, Please guide!

Comment: I face smaller issue before and the problem was in laravel queue it use cache to run. so the solution was by restart queue system and clear laravel cache

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try one of the following ways to overcome the issue, I faced a similar issue and resolved it by following ways -

1. Try deleting the cache files manually from Laravel from storage/framework/views
2. Upload the code directly into AWS for particular module without using the pipeline way
3. restart your server

   This will surely resolve your issue!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Laravel and angular application deployed on AWS,

I assume that bit bucket is pushing code and build commands are fired on every push
there are few things which can help you.

> 1. Try to build the angular side on every push, since angular builds hashes all the files in the dist folder
> 2. Try to delete the Laravel cached files which are stored in storage/framework/views
> 3. Check that on that your server is pointing to the right project folder

If any of the points from 1 or 2 works you can automate the process by passing CLI command after every push,

*Point 1 and 2 are achievable by passing CLI commands.*